# jframe send back when close the second jframe in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I am creating a Java application with NetBeans, a main JFrame containing menus. When I click a menu item and open another JFrame, and then close the second JFrame to return to the main JFrame, main JFrame was sent back and NetBeans IDE appears.

I must click ALT+TAB to show the main JFrame again and then when I reopen the second JFrame, everything goes OK.

I tested `JFrame.ToFront()`. Following screenshots describe the problem in steps:

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM8Pr.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th0C4.png)

[step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEHr2.png)

[step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlnIR.png)

[step 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp5zP.png)

[step 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWbsG.png)

[step 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfZ98.jpg)

Comment: You're going to need to find an [MCVE] first. (That's what any of us would need to find the error ourselves, whether online or in-person.) Find the area of code that causes the problem, and then [add that code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48652104/edit) to your post.

Comment: It is usually considered poor form to have multiple JFrames. It is much easier to accomplish this type of thing using a single JFrame and then creating extra JDialogs instead of extra JFrames.

Comment: I'd also consider [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for showing windows which gather small pieces of information from the user, [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for the ability to switch between a number of views within the same window or even [How to use TabbedPanes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) if you want the user to have the ability to choose which views they want to see

Comment: I'd also take the time to learn how to make UIs without the use of form editors, it ill make you a far better developer in the long run

Answer (score 0):

It is not very difficult. You just need to use

```
JFrame.requestFocus();
```

I hope that I could help you!